# Deserializing JSON objects as List<type> not working with asmx service

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-ajax, serialization

I am having trouble deserializing my JSON string.  I have a class of type `person` with public properties for sequence number of type int, first name, and last name.  I want to pass an array of these objects in JSON format and have them deserialized as a list so I can loop through them on the server, but ASP.NET says something about not being supported to be deserialized as an array.  I have validated the JSON I am producing, and it is valid.  Is there something special about the JSON that ASP.NET needs to have before it can deserialize?  The funny thing is if I serialize a list<person> object to JSON it looks exactly like the JSON I am producing.  I must be missing something...  To clarify, I'm using the ASP.NET Ajax library to deserialize.  This is what I get back from the web service:

> {"Message":"Type \u0027System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]\u0027 is not supported for deserialization of an array."

Actually unfortunately this doesn't seem to have anything to do with deserializing, it appears that you can't pass an array of JSON objects to an asmx web service.  Am I correct?  If you can't do that, is it possible to pass a collection of JSON objects to a web service and have them processed on the server with ASP.NET and C#?

#### Update:

OK, here is my code. Here is the person class:

```
public class person
{
    public person()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public int seq
    {
        get;
        set;
     }

    public string firstName
    {
        get;
        set;
     }
     public string lastName
     {
        get;
        set;
     }

}
```

And here is my JSON string:

```
[{"seq":1,"firstName":"Chris","lastName":"Westbrook"},
{"seq":2,"firstName":"sayyl","lastName":"westbrook"}]
```

And here is the code I'm using

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void updatePeople(string json)
    {
        IList<person> people = 
         new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IList<person>>(json);

        //do stuff...
    }
```

Comment: What are you using to serialize/deserialize json? What's the exact exception being thrown?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using the asp.net ajax library to deserialize.  i'm serializing the object to json manually based on form input, and when tested using the json validator linked to at json.org it says it is valid.

Answer (score 27):

I figured it out.  I wasn't wrapping my JSON in an object like ASP.NET Ajax requires.  For future viewers of this question, all JSON objects must be wrapped with a main object before being sent o the web service.  The easiest way to do this is to create the object in JavaScript and use something like json2.js to stringify it.  Also, if using an asmx web service, the objects must have a __type attribute to be serialized properly.  An example of this might be:

```
var person=new Object;
person.firstName="chris";
person.lastName="Westbrook";
person.seq=-1;
var data=new Object;
data.p=person;
JSON.stringify(data);
```

This will create a property called `p` on the `data` object that will wrap a person object.  This can then be linked to a parameter `p` in the web service.  Lists of type `person` are made similarly, accept using an array of persons instead of just a single object.  I hope this helps someone.

Comment: This was the exact solution to my similar problem. Thanks!

Comment: For array of Persons, do I need a p variable to wrap each Person , or do I need a p to wrap the whole array in the JSON string ?

Comment: @dan_l It depends on what your webservice expects. If your webservice is expecting `List<Person> people`, you should do `data.people = getPersonList()` or something. If your webservice expects `Person fred`, you should go for `data.fred = getFred()`. I'm 98% sure the parameter names should match.

Comment: I don't think new object is a thing in JavaScript; perhaps you ment new Object?

Answer (score 25):

Could you show the JSON string you are trying to deserialize and the way you are using the [Deserialize](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/documentation/live/mref/M_System_Web_Script_Serialization_JavaScriptSerializer_Deserialize%60%601_1_72eac341.aspx) method? The following works fine:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        class Person 
        {
            public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
        }

        public static void Main() 
        {
            string json = "[{\"SequenceNumber\":1,\"FirstName\":\"FN1\",\"LastName\":\"LN1\"},{\"SequenceNumber\":2,\"FirstName\":\"FN2\",\"LastName\":\"LN2\"}]";
            IList<Person> persons = new JavaScriptSerializer()
                .Deserialize<IList<Person>>(json);
            Console.WriteLine(persons.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Or even simpler, when you are doing the $.ajax(...) use

```
data:"{\"key\":"+JSON.stringify(json_array)+"}",
```

and then on the other side of the code, make your function use the parameter "object key"

```
[WebMethod]
public static return_type myfunction(object key){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

SERVER SIDE

```
[WebMethod]
public void updatePeople(object json)
```

CLIENT SIDE

```
var person = "[{"seq":1,"firstName":"Chris","lastName":"Westbrook"}
,{"seq":2,"firstName":"sayyl","lastName":"westbrook"}]";

var str = "{'json':'" + JSON.stringify(person) + "'}";
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is what type you have to deserialize. You are trying to deserialize type

> IList

but you should try to deserialize just

> List

Since interface can not be instantiated this might is the root problem.