# Get array out of json

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization

I would like to get data from an array in a json response.
This is the json:

```
{
    "program":{
        "title":"show",
        "image_url":"NOA_17.jpg"
    },
    "noa":[
        {
            "title":"Title1",
            "artist":"Artist1",
        },
        {
            "title":"Title2",
            "artist":"Artist2",
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to get Title1 & Artist1 out of there.

I hope there is someone who can help me with this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I wanted to try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/403377/743016
But the array is on the second level in the json so I supose that wouldn't work.

I also tried multiple other scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fix

```
        "artist":"Artist1",
        "artist":"Artist2",
```

to

```
        "artist":"Artist1"
        "artist":"Artist2"
```

E.g.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

class Sample {
    static void Main(){
        string json = File.ReadAllText("json.txt");
        var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var dic = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
        var noa = (ArrayList)dic["noa"];
        var noa_1 = (Dictionary<string, object>)noa[0];
        Console.WriteLine("title is {0}",noa_1["title"]);
        Console.WriteLine("artist is {0}",noa_1["artist"]);
    }
}
```