# JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having trouble deserializing an array in .NET MVC3, any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code snippet:

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
    JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string jsonData = reader.ReadToEnd();
    result = (BigCommerceOrderProducts)jsSerializer.Deserialize<BigCommerceOrderProducts>(jsonData);
}
```

Here's the subset of the data string returned by JSON as jsonData. I've remove extra fields.

```
"[
{\"id\":33,\"order_id\":230025,...},
{\"id\":34,\"order_id\":230025,...}
]"
```

Here are the objects:

```
[Serializable]
public class BigCommerceOrderProducts {
    public List<BigCommerceOrderProduct> Data { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class BigCommerceOrderProduct {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Order_id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
"Type 'Pxo.Models.BigCommerce.BigCommerceOrderProducts' is not supported for deserialization of an array.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is your json string wrapped in a .NET object? have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402996/deserializing-json-objects-as-listtype-not-working-with-asmx-service

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You should deserialize your json string to type `List<BigCommerceOrderProduct>`. No need for `BigCommerceOrderProducts` class

```
var myobj = jsSerializer.Deserialize<List<BigCommerceOrderProduct>>(jsonData);
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now. Let me try again and report back.

Answer (score 1):

This little proggy works fine for me.  Could be something unexpected in the response stream.

The json output is: {"Data":[{"Id":33,"Order_id":230025},{"Id":34,"Order_id":230025}]}

```
    JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 

    BigCommerceOrderProducts a = new BigCommerceOrderProducts();
    a.Data = new List<BigCommerceOrderProduct>();
    BigCommerceOrderProduct b = new BigCommerceOrderProduct();
    b.Id = 33;
    b.Order_id = 230025;

    a.Data.Add(b);

    b = new BigCommerceOrderProduct();
    b.Id = 34;
    b.Order_id = 230025;

    a.Data.Add(b);

    string x = jsSerializer.Serialize(a);
    Console.WriteLine(x);

    a = jsSerializer.Deserialize<BigCommerceOrderProducts>(x);

    Console.WriteLine(a.Data[0].Order_id);

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Chris, `"[ {\"id\":33,\"order_id\":230025,...}, {\"id\":34,\"order_id\":230025,...} ]"` is an array, on the other hand `{"Data":[{"Id":33,"Order_id":230025},{"Id":34,"Order_id":230025}]}` is an object containing an array. Two different things.

Comment: Yes, I know the difference.  Either the OP left off the "Data": part or the OP is attempting to deserialize an array to List<>.  So either the json returned in the response is incorrect, or the OP needs to deserialize to BigCommerceOrderProduct[] instead.

Comment: See my answer, response is correct and can be deserialized to List. (I never post a code before running on my machine or I mark it as *UNTESTED*)