# Deserializing a dynamic json to a c# class

Tags: c#, json

I have a dynamic json array of arrays which can be dynamic in nature. I would like to deserialize into a class. The "datatype" tag decides the datatype of C# class memeber

```
[{
  "model": "DeviceModel.DeviceInstance",
  "name": "My-Device",
  "variables": {
    "Variable1": {
      "SubVariable1": {
        "DataType": "Double",
        "Unit": "V",
        "High": "3.5",
        "Low": "3.2",
        "Nominal": "3.3"
      },
      "SubVariable2": {
        "DataType": "Double",
        "Unit": "A",
        "High": "10"
      }
    },
    "Variable2": {
      "DataType": "Int",
      "Unit": "bytes",
      "Max": "100000",
      "Low": "10000",
      "LowLow": "500"
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "ConstantProperty": {
      "PropertyName": {
        "DataType": "String",
        "Value": "12-34561"
      }
    }
  }
}
]
```

Comment: DataType is a string. Not different types. The *value* describes different datatypes. You should describe what the deserialised result would look like to avoid confusion.

Comment: Though the datatype is string based on the text bool, float or string the object needs to be deserialized to the particular type

Comment: @VivekRao What does that mean? How would you deserialize "test" as bool?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Theae are properties of a particular equipment and not the exact values. Based on these inputs certain action needs to be taken.

Comment: Then please remove that example (which is not even valid JSON) and add a meaningful example (does not have to be real data, just show your intentions)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have explained what I want to achieve with json string. Hope you could share a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have work around on your question and found below solution which works great
ref:
1.http://json2csharp.com/#

2.[JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033730/javascriptserializer-deserialize-array)

```
public class SubVariable1
    {
        public string DataType { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        public string High { get; set; }
        public string Low { get; set; }
        public string Nominal { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubVariable2
    {
        public string DataType { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        public string High { get; set; }
    }

    public class Variable1
    {
        public SubVariable1 SubVariable1 { get; set; }
        public SubVariable2 SubVariable2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Variable2
    {
        public string DataType { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        public string Max { get; set; }
        public string Low { get; set; }
        public string LowLow { get; set; }
    }

    public class Variables
    {
        public Variable1 Variable1 { get; set; }
        public Variable2 Variable2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class PropertyName
    {
        public string DataType { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConstantProperty
    {
        public PropertyName PropertyName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Properties
    {
        public ConstantProperty ConstantProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string model { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Variables variables { get; set; }
        public Properties properties { get; set; }
    }

    class Stackoverflow
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string strJSONData = "Your JSON Data";// Either read from string of file source
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<RootObject> objRootObjectList = jsSerializer.Deserialize<List<RootObject>>(strJSONData);
Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I hope this will help you.