# Array of objects. JSON deserialization. Please suggest

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, json, list

I am consuming a web service which returns a JSON string.

```
String str =[{"users":{"company":"abc","contact_Number":"999999999"}},
             {"users":{"company":"xyz","contact_Number":"888888888"}},
             {"users":{"company":"xxx","contact_Number":"555555555"}},
]
```

Unable to De-serialize.

```
class jsonmenuwrapper
        {
            public user[] users{ get; set; }
           // public List<user> listcontacts;
        }



public class user
        {
            public String company
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            public String contact_Number
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
}

JavaScriptSerializer sr= new JavaScriptSerializer();           

jsonmenuwrapper sr1 = sr.Deserialize<jsonmenuwrapper>(str);
```

throwing error.. jsonmenuwrapper' is not supported for deserialization of an array.

Can someone please guide me? Thanks..

Comment: You have an extra `,` at the end of your objs; probably a copy-paste error but I thought it was worth pointing out.

Comment: Here is the answer on the similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402996/deserializing-json-objects-as-listtype-not-working-with-asmx-service

Answer (score 2):

You are actually deserializing an array of users. There is no need for the `jsonmenuwrapper` class at all.

Just change 1 line:

```
List<user> sr1 = sr.Deserialize<List<user>>(str);
```

---

**Better Answer**

Actually, the data structure you are trying to deserialize is an array of your wrapper object, but each wrapper only contains 1 "users" not an array of them.  Here is a working setup with a unit test to show that its working:

```
public class jsonmenuwrapper
{
    public user users { get; set; }
}

public class user
{
    public String company { get; set; }
    public String contact_Number { get; set; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class JsonTests
{
    [Test]
    public void TestArrayDeserialization()
    {
        const string str =
@"[{""users"":{""company"":""abc"",""contact_Number"":""999999999""}},
{""users"":{""company"":""xyz"",""contact_Number"":""888888888""}},
{""users"":{""company"":""xxx"",""contact_Number"":""555555555""}}]";

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var data = serializer.Deserialize<List<jsonmenuwrapper>>(str);

        Assert.AreEqual(3, data.Count);

        Assert.AreEqual("abc", data[0].users.company);
        Assert.AreEqual("999999999", data[0].users.contact_Number);

        Assert.AreEqual("xyz", data[1].users.company);
        Assert.AreEqual("888888888", data[1].users.contact_Number);

        Assert.AreEqual("xxx", data[2].users.company);
        Assert.AreEqual("555555555", data[2].users.contact_Number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're casting a string to an array of objects...  I would expect it to throw an exception, but it's not, so try this:

```
String str ="[{\"users\":{\"company\":\"abc\",\"contact_Number\":\"999999999\"}},
             {\"users\":{\"company\":\"xyz\",\"contact_Number\":\"888888888\"}},
             {\"users\":{\"company\":\"xxx\",\"contact_Number\":\"555555555\"}}
]";
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't your classes need to be marked `Serializable`?

```
[Serializable]
public class jsonmenuwrapper
{
//...
}

[Serializable]
public class user
{
//...
}
```