# Use JSON to post a collection of models to webapi

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Here is my situation.  I built a web service that is designed to populate a report.  It receives a variable number of "findings" and then generates a report containing all of the findings.

Is there a way to post, using JSON, multiple findings at once, and have it bind to a List object?

EDIT:

So to be more specific, a finding would look like:

{ title: "title", description: "desc", rating: "High"}

I would like to be able to have my function look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post(IList<Finding> findings){
    //code...
}

public class Finding{
  public string title {get; set;}
  //...
}
```

So essentially I want to bind an array of those JSON findings into an IList

UPDATE:
I am looking to be able to have it bind automatically.  I am currently able to workaround by posting a JSON string (using JSON.stringify)

Here is my code that works:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post([FromBody]object jsonString){
IList<Finding> findingList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Finding>>(jsonString.toString());
//...
}
```

Any idea on how to get this to bind automatically, rather than having to convert?

Comment: Surely there must be. (I don't use ASP.Net's MVC stuff.) What have you tried? Where have you looked? This can't be a unique (or even rare) use case, wanting to receive a list of items. (The JSON side of it would presumably be an array.)

Comment: A quick search gives this, which may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402996/deserializing-json-objects-as-listtype-not-working-with-asmx-service (A more thorough search may find more useful information.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you stay with your solution :

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post([FromBody]object jsonString){
IList<Finding> findingList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Finding>>     (jsonString.toString());
//...
}
```

i think that you can :

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post(string jsonString){
IList<Finding> findingList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Finding>>     (jsonString);
//...
}
```

...And in your ajax call :

```
    $.ajax({
    ...
    data: JSON.Stringify(data),
    ...
    });
```

OR,

you can try something like (it comes from my code) :

```
    var LoginFormSubmitHandler = function (e) {
    var $form = $(this);
    // We check if jQuery.validator exists on the form
    if (!$form.valid || $form.valid()) {

        $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serializeArray())
        ...
```

...and can you show the value of $form.serializeArray() ??

Comment: Thanks!  I just found the JSON.Stringify(data) method to work well.  Took some doing to parse it, but worked great!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but your question is too general to answer in depth. Using the the `HttpRequest` class you can specify that you are doing a post and make the payload a JSON blob. That blob can be a list of objects. On the server side you can read that data and serialize it. I would recommend using JSON.NET to do this. You can do it in a very static way, say your list is a list of objects of type `A` or types `B, C, or D` which inherit from `A`. If you create those object definitions in code JSON.NET can take the raw json (an array of these objects) and convert it into an array of the objects which you've defined in code.

json.NET docs:
http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx
HttpRequest docs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx
An abstraction layer for HttpRequest:
http://restsharp.org/

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly. No ugly JSON de-serialization.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Customer))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostCustomer(IEnumerable<Customer> customers)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    db.Customers.AddRange(customers);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

And call:

```
...api/Customers
```

with POST form body as:

Url: .../api/

```
[
  {
    "SampleProperty": "SampleValue1"
    ...
    ...
  },
  {
    "SampleProperty": "SampleValue2"
  }
]
```